# How to update PERC H700 when used in a Dell R410 server?

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, dell-perc

I have a PERC H700 running in a Dell R410 server which works fine. However when I try to update the firmware using the Dell package I get a message "This update package is not compatible with your system..."

I tried using the Lifecyle Controller to update and that didn't pickup any updates so it didn't help. How can I get the H700 firmware updated on a Dell system such as this?

Comment: Well... is the update package you're trying to install compatible with your system? Where did you get it? How do you know it's compatible? Have you tried updating it using the SUU?

Comment: @joeqwerty I actually did get it from support.dell.com using the service code of the server which is odd but the H700 was never something they offered for the R410. Good question, I wonder if it's the OS which is 2012 R2 just as selected on the support site. I'll check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally landed on the right solution from a google search realizing the download I got from Dell was for the H700 ADAPTER when I have the H700 INTEGRATED. Problem solved.